# Add a scale bar to a ggplot map that has been scaled using coord_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I've produced a map using the sf package and ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
state_prov <- rnaturalearth::ne_states(c("united states of america", "canada"), returnclass="sf")
x <- ggplot(data=state_prov) + 
geom_sf()+
coord_sf(xlim=c(-170, -95), ylim=c(40, 75)) 
print(x)
```

which produces the following map in Rstudio:
[image: blank plot]

That's great, but I need to add a scale bar to it. When I try to modify the code using ggsn, I don't see the scale bar at all.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
state_prov <- rnaturalearth::ne_states(c("united states of america", "canada"), returnclass="sf")
x <- ggplot(data=state_prov) + 
geom_sf()+
coord_sf(xlim=c(-170, -95), ylim=c(40, 75)) +
ggsn::scalebar(state_prov, location="topleft", dist = 50, dist_unit = "km", 
                 transform=TRUE, model="WGS84", height=0.1)
print(x)
```

I've tried to change the height, st.dist, and location with no success. I can see a poorly scaled scalebar when I remove the call to coord_sf(), making me believe that ggsn does not recognize that the map is being zoomed in by coord_sf().

How do I fix this? ggsn does not seem to be easily modifiable. I'm open to using another package or method, but I do need to continue calling ggplot in a similar manner since I have a much more complicated map based on the same structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mention, if you comment out the `coord_sf` part of your code the scale bar shows up. My guess is `ggsn::scalebar` must be getting its `topleft` location from the entire `state_prov` dataset, and when you zoom using `coord_sf` the scalebar is cropped out.

**Edit:** beware of extreme distortion when putting a scale bar on a map with lat/long projection at this scale: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41373569/12400385

Here are a couple of options for getting a scale bar to show up.

**Option 1**

Use `ggspatial::annotation_scale` instead of `ggsn` which seems to recognize the zoom as defined in `coord_sf`.

```
ggplot(data=state_prov) + 
  geom_sf()+
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-170, -95), ylim=c(40, 75)) +
  ggspatial::annotation_scale(location = 'tl')
```

[image]

**Option 2**

Use your original code but crop `state_prov` before plotting so `scalebar` can find the correct `topleft`.

```
state_prov_crop <- st_crop(state_prov, xmin=-170, xmax = -95, ymin = 40, ymax = 75)

ggplot(data=state_prov_crop) + 
  geom_sf()+
  #coord_sf(xlim=c(-170, -95), ylim=c(40, 75)) +
  ggsn::scalebar(state_prov_crop, location="topleft", dist = 50, dist_unit = "km", 
                 transform=TRUE, model="WGS84", height=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Option 1 worked perfectly for me. And don't worry, I'm going to change the projection at some point to avoid distortion issues.

Answer (score 0):

In `ggsn::scalebar` you can, instead of `data=`, directly supply min/max coordinates for your map,

```
ggsn::scalebar(x.min=5,x.max=17,y.min=40,y.max=48,...)
```

and specify the relative location of the scalebar as you did with `location=`.